# Combine values of span classe and title attribute

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Cant figure out how to get a combination of the span attribute 'title' and the text value of the span class num

```
<ul>
       <li>
          <span class="abc" title="HOUSES"> </span>
          <span class="num">1</span>
       </li>
       <li>
          <span class="def" title="CARS"> </span>
          <span class="num">2</span>
       </li>
       <li>
          <span class="ghj" title="AGE"> </span>
          <span class="num">90</span>
       </li>
</ul>
```

How can i get attributes like ?

HOUSES = 1

CARS = 2

AGE = 90

This is where i am but not solving the problem so far

```
    for li_tag in soup.find_all('ul'):
        for span_tag in li_tag.find_all('li'):
            for span in span_tag.find_all('span'):
                print(span)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how can try to get the desired results:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<ul>
   <li>
      <span class="abc" title="HOUSES"> </span>
      <span class="num">1</span>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span class="abc" title="CARS"> </span>
      <span class="num">2</span>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span class="abc" title="AGE"> </span>
      <span class="num">90</span>
   </li>
</ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for items in soup.find_all("li"):
    title = items.find("span").get("title")
    number = items.select_one("span:nth-of-type(2)").text
    print("{} = {}".format(title,number))
```

you can try like this as well:

```
for items in soup.find_all(class_="num"):
    title = items.find_previous_sibling()['title']
    number = items.text
    print("{} = {}".format(title,number))
```

This is another way:

```
for items in soup.select("[title]"):
    title = items.get("title")
    number = items.find_next().text
    print("{} = {}".format(title,number))
```

Or like this:

```
for items in soup.find_all(lambda e: e.get("title")):
    title = items.get("title")
    number = items.find_next_sibling().text
    print("{} = {}".format(title,number))
```

Output:

```
HOUSES = 1
CARS = 2
AGE = 90
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake the class always Chan

Comment: The class always change , I edited the post , thanks

Comment: If you do not wish to use `selector` then just replace the line with `number = items.find("span").find_next().text`.